# Angular component binding to Id attribute

Tags: angular

I have a component which I need to dynamically set the id attribute for. This is made up of a some text and another variable, example below.

```
export class TestComponent {
    @Input() public groupId: number = null;
}
```

The id of this component should be 'fg1' if the groupId variable is 1, 'fg2' if the group is 2 etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Angular 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach in the latest versions of Angular (15+ I believe)

```js
export class TestComponent {
    @Input({ transform: (v: number) => v ? `fg${v}` : null })
    @HostBinding('attr.id')
    groupId: number = null;
}
```

EDIT : to not change the value, v15 :

```js
export class TestComponent {
    @Input()
    set groupId(v: number) {
      if (v) this.id = `fg${v}`;
    }
    @HostBinding('attr.id')
    id: string = null;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this change the value of the groupId? I believe transform is also version 16 whereas I am currently limited to version 15 unfortunately

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your comment

Comment: That's great, seems to do what I need. Thanks very much for the help